# Oracle regexp_substr - how extract text excluding marker characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string that comes in this format

```
Transaction 'pqr_111_xyz_222(Aaaa Bbbb Cccc - 3333)' failed due to connection error
```

I need to extract the text between ' and (.

pqr_111_xyz_222 in this example.

The following query returns **'pqr_111_xyz_222(**

```
select regexp_substr('Transaction ''pqr_111_xyz_222(Aaaa Bbbb Cccc - 3333)'' failed due to connection error', '''.+\(') from dual;
```

How do I modify the regex (or use any other technique that can included within this single query) so that the markers ' and ( are excluded and I get just **pqr_111_xyz_222** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions115.htm) instead:

```
regexp_replace('Transaction ''pqr_111_xyz_222(Aaaa Bbbb Cccc - 3333)'' failed due to connection error', '.*''(.+)\(.*', '\1')
```

Comment: +1. There isn't any straight forward way to do this with oracle.

Answer (score 2):

```
select regexp_substr('Transaction ''pqr_111_xyz_222(Aaaa Bbbb Cccc - 3333)'' failed due to connection error', '\w+',1,2) from dual;
```

Comment: Clever solution. `regexp_substr` is used here in not well known case.

Answer (score 1):

You could surround the function call  with substr and instr to remove the first and last characters of the result.  Downside is that I think you'd have to have an extra call to regexp_substr in order to get the length of the result to pass to the substr/instr.

Answer (score 1):

This book is a decent source if you want to dig into using backreference (required in regexp_replace option) [http://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Reference-OReilly-ebook/dp/B0026OR38A/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1323109619&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0026OR38A)